# What is a good series of books/programs to start learning from, if any?

Tags: learning, website

I started learning Japanese when I was in high school as a hobby but have limited time now that I am working full time, what books or programs would you suggest for someone wanting to learn Beginning/Intermediate Japanese.

Also are there groups that one can join that would allow me to practice with others so as to expand my understanding and help me retain the vocabulary?

Thanks for any input you may have it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried lang-8?

Comment: I'm very sorry, but this is off topic for the site.

Comment: No, what is it?

Comment: How can it be off topic? It is asking a legitimate question regarding me trying to expand my knowledge of Japanese.

Comment: 名前がやばいとか・・？Death for you allっていうとこ。。。ごめん No offense meant

Comment: Thank you @Chocolate, that was quite helpful. I didn't know about that site.

Comment: @deth4uall-san, Please drop by and post something on this website too if you have time... http://www.japanologic.com/portal.php

Comment: Asking for recommendations on learning resources is off topic. This site is not for open discussions on how to learn the language, it's for specific questions about the language. Look at these similar questions that were closed for the same reason: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8/whats-the-best-utility-for-identifying-kanji http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4067/electronic-dictionary-recommendations-specific-models-and-edict-based-app http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4413/how-can-i-improve-my-japanese-vocabulary-grammar-and-listening-skills

Comment: Ah I remember the 3rd one. So...this post will be closed too?

Comment: First of all, good on you for wanting to continue learning Japanese. However, even if questions about learning were on topic, rather than seen as too "unrelated", the question would be a little bit too broad. You might want to read the blog post http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ I'm +1ing anyway because I think -1 is too low a score for such a question.